# Pythagorean Triple Generator

Tags: go

I'm just playing about with Go, and am trying to solve some project euler problems to get used to it.

I've created a generator function for Pythagorean triples, using a channel which returns a set of 3 integers for the sides, like so (HCF implements Euclid's algorithm for finding greatest common divisor or highest common factor in this part of the world):

```
package main
import "fmt"

func HCF(a, b int) int {
    if a % b == 0 {
        return b
    } else {
        return HCF(b, a%b)
    }
}


func PythagTriple() chan [3]int {

    ch := make(chan [3]int)

    go func() {
        for m := 2; ; m++ {
            for n := m%2 + 1; n < m; n += 2 {
                if HCF(m, n) == 1 {
                    var triple [3]int
                    triple[0] = m*m - n*n
                    triple[1] = 2 * m * n
                    triple[2] = m*m + n*n
                    ch <- triple
                }
            }
        }
    }()

    return ch
}

func main() {

    ch := PythagTriple()
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Println(<- ch)
    }
}
```

Questions:

1. Do I need to do anything with the channel, or will it close and clean up when it goes out of scope?
2. Is there a better way of creating a quick array than how I've done it?
3. Is this idiomatic Go, or am I barking up the wrong tree entirely?  I've just started and am not sure if I'm doing it right!

Don't worry too much about efficiency of the algorithm; I'm not too concerned about speed at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. With respect to cleaning up the channel:

   As-is your goroutine will never exit and release it's reference to the channel so it will never get garbage collected. That's fine for something like this where `main` reads what it wants and then exits. If you want the ability to stop it you can use a stop signal/channel (e.g. see the Go blog [Pipeline](https://blog.golang.org/pipelines) and/or [Context](https://blog.golang.org/context) articles.
2. Creating the array:

   Already answered, `ch <- [3]int{x, y, z}` is likely the most concise way and is quite reasonable. See also [Composite Literals in the spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals) for when you want to this with a struct instead of an array/slice.
3. Idiomatic Go:

   It look okay to me (except for `gofmt`ing). Run [`gofmt`](https://blog.golang.org/go-fmt-your-code), [`golint`](https://github.com/golang/lint), and [`go vet`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/vet) on your code (`go fmt` all the time and before check-in, the others as required and consider the output as recommendations).

   Also (re-)read [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html) and the Go Author [code review comments](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments) (the later should probably be read more as a recomendation rather than rules, but I prefer to try and follow it).

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestions - particularly the hints about releasing the channel for garbage collection, suspected I wasn't quite getting that bit right!

Answer (score 2):

Not a Go expert but I think you should be able to define your array of values as you declare it :

```
triple := [...]int{m*m - n*n, 2 * m * n, m*m + n*n}
```

[Source](http://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals)

Comment: This I think is one of the bigger improvements overall (and gets rid of the `var triple [3]int` declaration.

Comment: Thank you - have just skimmed through the docs so far, must have missed that way of declaring arrays, that's much clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Using Josay's suggestion then, is this the cleanest way to do it?

```
package main
import "fmt"

func HCF(a, b int) int {
    if a % b == 0 {
        return b
    } else {
        return HCF(b, a%b)
    }
}


func PythagTriple() chan [3]int {

    ch := make(chan [3]int)

    go func() {
        for m := 2; ; m++ {
            for n := m%2 + 1; n < m; n += 2 {
                if HCF(m, n) == 1 {
                    ch <- [3]int{m*m + n*n, 2*m*n, m*m - n*n}
                }
            }
        }
    }()

    return ch
}

func main() {

    ch := PythagTriple()
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Println(<- ch)
    }
}
```

Comment: Self-answers should also incorporate specific changes made.  If you'd like further review instead, post a new follow-up question.